# R Download csv file from website (R-curl)

Tags: r, csv, download, rcurl

I am trying to find an easy method to download that csv. `https://www.otcmarkets.com/research/stock-screener` My problem is that it seems like there is no seperate URL for the file (Or have i missed something?!). I would like to find a solution with the `library(RCurl)` package. I can only think of solutions in respect to a rem session which seems to be a bit overkill. Any help is appreciated... Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: That url is not pointing to a csv file.

Comment: Like i eleborated in the question. There seems to be no seperate URL.

Comment: Maybe that is what you meant but that is not what the question says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read.csv("https://www.otcmarkets.com/research/stock-screener/api/downloadCSV")
```

You can see the URL in your browser when you hit the Download button.

Comment: Thank you very much. Firefox 91.0.2 does not show the URL. But chrome browser did. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.